# Infinite Scroll works on some categories

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite scroll on my website, but i'm facing a problem. On some categories the infinite scroll works just fine, on some other i keep getting a message "Your nextSelector found no elements", even when the pagination > 1 page.

Working Category:  `http://192.185.242.52/opsinews/category/kinonia/`

Non-working Category: `http://192.185.242.52/opsinews/category/psichologia-metafisiki/`

This is the code i'm using to generate the pagination:

> // Custom Pagination by KRIESI
>
> function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {
>        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
>
> ```
>  global $paged;
>  if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
>
>  if($pages == '')
>  {
>      global $wp_query;
>      $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
>      if(!$pages)
>      {
>          $pages = 1;
>      }
>  }   
>
>  if(1 != $pages)
>  {
>      echo "<div class='pagination'>";
>      if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
>      if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";
>
>      for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
>      {
>          if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
>          {
>              echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."'
> ```
>
> class='inactive' >".$i."";
>                }
>            }
>
> ```
>      if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a class='next_link' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged +
> ```
>
> 1)."'>›";
>            if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "»";
>            echo "\n";
>        } }

and this is the code to initialise the infinite scroll:

> /* Loading...\",\"finishedMsg\":\"No
>   additional
>   posts.\",\"img\":\"http:\\\/\\\/174.132.169.16\\\/opsinews\\\/wp-content\\\/plugins\\\/infinite-scroll\\\/img\\\/ajax-loader.gif\"},\"nextSelector\":\"a.next_link\",\"navSelector\":\".pagination\",\"itemSelector\":\".article-item\",\"contentSelector\":\".article-items-wrapper\",\"debug\":true,\"behavior\":\"\",\"callback\":\"\\t\\t\\\/* Lazyload
>   *\\\/\\r\\n\\t\\t$(\\\"img.lazy\\\").lazyload({\\r\\n\\t\\t\\teffect : \\\"fadeIn\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\tthreshold :
>   200,\\r\\n\\t\\t\\tfailure_limit : 10\\r\\n\\t\\t});\"}"; /* ]]> */

Answer (score 0):

you have a javascript error on one of the pages, with then prevents further javascript.
your error is here

```
//remember dropdown
var drop = document.getElementById('time_entry_activity_id');
drop.onchange = function(){
GM_setValue("job", drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

try and check first if drop is an object, try something like this

```
if (drop != null && drop.value == '') {
   ..... your code ....
}
```

Comment: it was there when i viewt the site, now however you have console logs on the working page and _Your nextSelector found no elements._  on the non working so you clearly have different javascript loading on them

Comment: nope. The odd thing is that both categories are using the same template file, category.php

Comment: on a closer look, it seems that the 'pagination' code does not add the next/previous buttons.